# DoubleAnimation reverse 2x faster

Tags: c#, animation, storyboard

I have a `DoubleAnimation` set for a `DropShadowEffect` to change `Blur Radius` up and down producing a glowing animated shadow like this:

```
DropShadowEffect DS = new DropShadowEffect();

                /// Whatever DS settings here

                Target.Effect = DS;

                DoubleAnimation DSr = new DoubleAnimation(0, 25, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)));
                DSr.AutoReverse = true;
                DSr.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;

                DS.BeginAnimation(DropShadowEffect.BlurRadiusProperty, DSr);
```

It takes `20` milliseconds to make one step forward, and total time of `500` milliseconds.

Is it possible to make the reverse action step back once every `10` milliseconds with total time of `250` milliseconds (two times normal speed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i figured i can use `Completed` event to do something like this:

```
DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation(0.0, 1.0);

animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);

animation.Completed += (s, e) =>
        {
            If (target.opacity == 1)
            {
                animation.From = 1.0;
                animation.To = 0.0;
                animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250);

                element.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, animation);
            }
            else
            {
                animation.From = 0.0;
                animation.To = 1.0;
                animation.SpeedRatio = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);

                element.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, animation);
            }
        }

element.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, animation);
```